# My laptop won't connect to wifi

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-10, acer-aspire

I have **Acer V5-571** with windows 10.

> it works very wellbut now it says it can't connect and the other people with me can connect. I have the password correct so I can't figure out what's wrong. I tried rebooting it. It didn't work.
>
> I try this
>   1. Open windows command prompt Start\ Run\cmd\ok
>
> 2. To release your Ip address ipconfig/release
>      Enter
> 3. To renew your IP address ipconfig/renew
>      Enter

I have Unistalled the driver of WIFI card but don't work neither.I want know is my laptop or my router?

**Some advice from you.
Thnx**

Answer (score 0):

Troubleshoot by right clicking on the wifi icon in the right bottom end of the screen.Then try Searching the error it describes in google.But I think It must missing some net protocols.To fix this Go to ControlPanel>Network and Internet>Network And sharing Centre>Change adapter Settings.Then right click on WIFI then Properties then make sure IPv6 is disabled.Then Click on IPv4 and on Install then protocols click on each and every protocols then Install.HoPeItHeLpS!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: i try what you say but nothing change

Comment: Say what the troubleshoot windows says

Comment: problem with the access point or wireless card...but i dont undertsand why because other devices are connected to my wifi